# Erro na Coluna Discriminator EF code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp, code-first

Estou fazendo um projeto em asp.net, estou utilizando classes em C# para fazer a conexão com o banco, porem, toda a vez que tento inserir um usuário no banco, gera o seguinte erro:

> nome da coluna "Discriminator" inválido

Obs: Meu banco já existia, utilizei o code first from database.

Esse é meu método de cadastrar:

```
public virtual void cadastrar(T item) 
{
    context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    context.SaveChanges();

}
```

A classe que o EF gerou:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Banco : DbContext
{
    public Banco()
        : base("BDbuffet")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Alimento> Alimentos { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bebida> Bebidas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Festa> Festas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Garcon> Garcons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GarconsContratado> GarconsContratados { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Iten> Itens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Alimento>()
            .Property(e => e.nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Alimento>()
            .Property(e => e.descricao)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Alimento>()
            .Property(e => e.imagemAlimento)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Alimento>()
            .Property(e => e.valorUnitario)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Alimento>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Itens)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Alimento)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idAlimentos);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bebida>()
            .Property(e => e.nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bebida>()
            .Property(e => e.descricao)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bebida>()
            .Property(e => e.imagemBebida)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bebida>()
            .Property(e => e.valorUnitario)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bebida>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Itens)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Bebida)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idBebidas);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .Property(e => e.local)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .Property(e => e.data)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .Property(e => e.status)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .Property(e => e.valorTotal)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .HasMany(e => e.GarconsContratados)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Festa)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idFesta)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Festa>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Itens)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Festa)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idFesta);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .Property(e => e.nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .Property(e => e.cpf)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .Property(e => e.sexo)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .Property(e => e.telefone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .Property(e => e.email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Garcon>()
            .HasMany(e => e.GarconsContratados)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Garcon)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idGarcon)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GarconsContratado>()
            .Property(e => e.fone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GarconsContratado>()
            .Property(e => e.email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GarconsContratado>()
            .Property(e => e.valorPago)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GarconsContratado>()
            .Property(e => e.status)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Iten>()
            .Property(e => e.valorTotal)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.cpf)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.endereco)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.cidade)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.fone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.login)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.senha)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.aceitoTermos)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.email)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Erros no campo "Discriminator" geralmente são relacionados com algum caso de herança entre classes mapeadas no EF, pois é padrão dele usar um campo assim para definir quem é a classe que deve implementar o registro. No seu caso, existe alguma classe que herde de Usuario?

Comment: Sim tem duas classes, Cliente e administrador  que herda Usuário

Comment: Como  implemento o registro ?

Comment: Caso essas classes não precisem estar mapeadas (como parece ser pelo seu exemplo), você deve explicitar pro EF que elas não devem ser incluídas no mapeamento. Por exemplo: modelBuilder.Ignore<TipoQueHerdaUsuario>();

Comment: Não modificou nada continua com o mesmo erro, fui tentar realizar o cadastro em outra classe que não faz herança com outra e ocorreu o mesmo erro

Comment: e apareceu esse erro também "The entity type Cliente is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: Mas essas classes Cliente e Administrador possuem campos que fazem parte da sua base? Eles deveriam estar mapeados?

Comment: Aliás, qual seria o relacionamento entre Usuario, Cliente e Administrador tanto na base quanto nas suas classes?

Comment: A tabela de usuários teria todos que utilizam o sistema, que incluiria o adm e o Cliente

Comment: Consegui ver o problema, era com o relacionamento com o adm

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas

Comment: De nada! Se puder, por favor crie uma resposta indicando o que estava faltando, para ajudar futuros usuários com esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Achei o erro, O code first quando mapeia o banco cria uma coluna a mais chamada discriminator, o que eu estava gerando era que eu fiz uma classe herdar o administrador herdar Usuarios que corresponde a tabela no banco, mas essa classe adm não tinha coluna discriminator porque não era do banco, aí ocorria o erro, após remover essa herança o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Tem uma coisa ai que você não precisa importa o  public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }.... não selecione nada que tenha diagram nas suas tabelas